# What virtual currency is currently the most profitable with an Nvidia GPU?

Tags: mining-profitability, gpu-mining

By most profitable, I mean the coin that returns the most profit for 
lower-hashing GPU's.

Answer (score 0):

As of right this instant (9/26/13) feather coin is, but if your asking this for mining purposes then I suggest what you do is point your miner at a multi coin pool such as [this one](https://www.multipool.us/). These pools make sure that you're always getting the most bang for your hash rate by continually switching to whatever coin is currently most profitable.